# Array List replace all elements with last one

Tags: java, arraylist

I have these three classes in java and am having a problem with array list. Why does array list replace all elements with last entry?

arraylist.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class arraylist {
    public ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
}
```

circle.java

```
public class Circle {
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

run.java

```
public class run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        arraylist ar=new arraylist();
        Circle c = new Circle();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            c.x = s.nextInt();
            c.y = s.nextInt();
            boolean status = ar.circles.add(c);
            if (status)
                System.out.print("added to circles ...");
        }
        System.out.print("########################################");
        for (Circle c2:ar.circles)
        {
            System.out.print("\nx=" + c2.x + "   y=" + c2.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RedRoboHood isnt the name of the class previous defined?

Comment: Tip: follow coding conventions. Class names should start with a capital letter. Variable and method names, with a lowercase letter. So `ArrayList` would be the name of a class, `arrayList` the name of a variable, and it's best never to use something like `arraylist`. Also, there is no point in just declaring a class like that. Just use the `ArrayList<Circle>` directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only created one `Circle`, before the `for` loop begins. You are adding the same `Circle` object each time through the loop.  Also, you are changing that `Circle`'s properties each time, so that the last circle's properties are the ones still visible in the one object.

Instead, create a new `Circle` object inside the `for` loop, one for each iteration.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    Circle c = new Circle();
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to move

```
Circle c = new Circle();
```

inside the `for` loop. Right now, there's only one 'Circle', and everytime you call `c.x = s.nextInt();` or `c.y = s.nextInt();` the coordinates of that Circle get updated.

Answer (score 1):

You keep overriding the same instance of `Circle` (i.e., `c`). Instead, you should create a new instance each time you want to add an element to the list:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    Circle c = new Circle(); // new instance!
    c.x = s.nextInt();
    c.y = s.nextInt();
    boolean status = ar.circles.add(c);
    if (status)
        System.out.print("added to circles ...");
}
```

Comment: thank you Glorfindel . I understand what was the problem .